# How to decompress and access a 10 year old ACE file?

Tags: compression, ace

I'm trying to unarchive some old photos I have that are stored in ACE format (via WinACE). The file was created a little over 10 years ago.

I'm running `unace l photos.ace` and getting what seems to be a full list files.

When I run `unace e photos.ace` I and am getting an error.

The output is:

```
UNACE v1.2    public version

Processing archive: photos.ace

Authenticity Verification:
created on 16.8.2002 by *UNREGISTERED VERSION*


Mt. St. Helens
 Analyzing
File compressed with unknown method. Decompression not possible.

Error occurred
```

Does anyone have any suggestions/ideas on how to extract these?

Edit: I've downloaded the linux version (v2.5) from winace.com's site with the same effect.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the
[unace-nonfree](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=unace-nonfree) [image: Install unace-nonfree] package.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try WinAce in wine or a VirtualBox.

Comment: [You do not need to add your signature.](http://askubuntu.com/faq#signatures)